# Receiving multiple Values from android via Bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, android, data

my question is, how can I receive 3 integer values in Arduino, which I send from my android phone. I send all 3 values at the same time and I also need to read them in about the same time.
I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other constraints, send them as a text with delimiters and a  terminating character.
e.g. something like `"123;45;678\n"`

On the arduino, either manually check for those delimiters and convert the digits to a number on the fly, or use `strtok`  and `atoi` after reading the whole line.